# Cheap uN Force sensor

Tags: sensor

I need to measure small changes in the force applied by two fingers holding a force sensor. The changes are in the order of the micro-Newton. The commercial system for making these types of measurements cost several thousands of dollars. Do you know if there are cheaper alternatives that can be used?

Comment: You want a force sensor to measure the force being applied to a force sensor?

Comment: A sketch would definitely help here

Comment: @Transistor: we need to measure the force between the two fingers that hold the sensor.

Comment: @DPF: here are the specifications of the sensor: https://www.ati-ia.com/products/ft/ft_models.aspx?id=Nano17. We need to reproduce an experiment from a paper and only need the measurement of changes in pressure applied by the fingers, which is very tiny in our experimental conditions. I wonder whether this sensor is too much for this scope and we could actually use something cheaper

Comment: Your description is lacking information. What is the dynamic range and absolute force range you want to measure? Compression or tension or both? Which axes? Also Torque? In case of dynamic uniaxial compression (no static force!), consider the piezoelectric principle using a high gain charge amplifier. This could be a rather cheap approach, given that you have access to a charge amp and either a well defined piezo element/stack or a possibility to calibrate.

Comment: "I wonder whether this sensor is too much for this scope and we could actually use something cheaper" You were given several cheaper options that you keep completely ignoring without any explanation or providing additional details.

Comment: @Maple: I am not ignoring the comments. I am trying to understand them. We are trying to replicate the experiment from this study http://www.giacomonovembre.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Novembre_etal_2019.pdf, but the equipment is too expensive for us. That is why I would like to simplify the hardware if possible.

Comment: @DFP: I only nee to measure compression.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is to measure something else, e.g. use lever system to move feather-light shutter over light sensor, or magnet on a long arm next to hall sensor, or beam of light deflected by the movable prism etc.

Note that the last one can be made practically friction-less, and the sensitivity is defined only by the length of the beam, so you can make extremely sensitive device for very little cost.

Answer (score 0):

You're after a strain gauge of a suitable force range. Probably a full bridge type if you need high accuracy. This gets hooked up to a differential ADC. Should be able to source most of it off the shelf for under $100

Edit: 
[Vishay micro strain gauge product guide](https://www.thermofisher.com.au/Uploads/file/Environmental-Industrial/Process-Monitoring-Industrial-Instruments/Sound-Vibration-Stress-Monitoring/Stress-Analysis/IP_L2A-C2A-Low-Cost-Pre-Wired-Strain-Gauges_Catalogue.pdf)

You can buy a number of there models for about $30 on digikey,

Take the Vishay micro measurement series, they measure full scale as low as ~1500µε full scale, now this is not directly force. instead you then bond that strain gauge to something that will compress / deflect in that range of strain under your desired range of force, which is easy with a thin enough piece of metal / other material,

To get strain, Force / Area / Youngs Modulus of the material

Comment: Do you know any that can measure strain in the micronewton range?

Comment: Updated answer, yes you can measure in that force range, just comes down to the material you pick for the strain gauge to measure the deflection in,

Comment: I think I start to see what you mean.